# Scroll panel based on mouse position in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, scroll, panel

I'm trying to make an autoscroll enabled panel that will scroll if the mouseposition.x > panel.location.y
However, I cannot seem to find a panel.scroll() function. Is there a way to programable make the control scroll? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
panel.VerticalScroll.Value = 50
```

and

```
panel.HorizontalScroll.Value = 50
```

you can use

```
panel.VerticalScroll.Minimum, panel.VerticalScroll.Maximum, 
panel.HorizontalScroll.Minimum, panel.HorizontalScroll.Maximum
```

to check max and min values